# Having trouble saving info to clipboard with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm trying to use Tkinter to save a string to my clipboard. While it seems to work if I manually set string equal to something in the program, it doesn't work if my program asks for input.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk


def copy(text):
    r = Tk()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(text)
    r.update()
    r.destroy()


def main():
    string = input('Word(s) to convert\n\t').upper() #this works if string = 'something' and not string = input()

    strcon = [' '.join(string)]
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        strcon.append(string[i+1])

    strcon = '\n'.join(strcon)
    print(strcon)
    print('You can now paste to destination')
    copy(strcon)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Define: doesn't work, because it worked the same for me. Are you sure you're using python 3?

Comment: I'm confident. The problem is that there is nothing on the clipboard after the program executes. The only way I have gotten it to work is using r.mainloop() and just force closing the app.

Comment: I tried on both Windows and Debian and they both worked, perhaps there's something else?